# How do I label values for cycle numbers in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a columns, iterate 1 to 3. I need a cycle number, which presents in the mid column. How do I use pandas to get the second column number please?

here is the table:

```
column  | I need   |Note
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
2       | 1        |first cycle although not starting from 1
3       | 1        |first cycle although not starting from 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 2        |second cycle
2       | 2        |second cycle
3       | 2        |second cycle
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 3        |
2       | 3        |
3       | 3        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 4        |
2       | 4        |
3       | 4        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 5        |
2       | 5        |
3       | 5        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 6        |
2       | 6        |
3       | 6        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1       | 7        |7th cycle and does have to end in 3
2       | 7        |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your sample data working first difference by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare less like `0` and last cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df['new'] = df['column'].diff().lt(0).cumsum() + 1
```

If values are strings is possible encoding to numeric by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with dictionary:

```
df['new'] = df['column'].map({'1':0, '2':2, '3':3}).diff().lt(0).cumsum() + 1
```

---

```
print (df)
    column  I need  new
0        2       1    1
1        3       1    1
2        1       2    2
3        2       2    2
4        3       2    2
5        1       3    3
6        2       3    3
7        3       3    3
8        1       4    4
9        2       4    4
10       3       4    4
11       1       5    5
12       2       5    5
13       3       5    5
14       1       6    6
15       2       6    6
16       3       6    6
17       1       7    7
18       2       7    7
```

EDIT: You can create dictioanry for map by all value in one group with `enumerate`:

```
d = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(['1','2','3'])}
#if possible create groups by all unique values - check order before
#print (df.columns.unique())
#d = {v:k for k, v in enumerate(df.columns.unique()}
df['new'] = df['column'].map(d).diff().lt(0).cumsum() + 1
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if the given 'column' has string values, can't be cumsumed?

Comment: @S.Gu - no, unfortunately not.

Comment: @S.Gu: if your string values are functionning like a cycle ("first", "second", "third", "first", ...) , just encode the string as integers with `map` or `replace` and a dictionnary.

Comment: @jezrael im lucky only need to map 5 values. what if the cycle is long? say 30 values a cycle? lol

Comment: @jezrael: you can improve it by taking `df.column.unique()` as the array in enumerate I think :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most simple solution, as you just need to define the value/string that starts the interval:

```
start_val = 1 # the value / string which starts the cycle
df['new'] = ((df['column'] == start_val) | pd.isna(df['column'].shift())).cumsum()
```

If you have nan's in `df['column']` than add `.fillna(0 / '')` before the `.shift()`